# Button script wasn't updated from the change set

Tags: custom-button, deployment, change-set

Some time ago I deployed change set to the production - 1 button and 4 validation rules. Now I have noticed that despite deployment status was "Deploy: Succeeded", button code wasn't updated (but validation rules was).

How can it be possible, that button script wasn't updated from the change set?

Comment: Go to Change Set that was deployed. Check the Button if it has updated code.

Comment: Checked, it has.

Comment: Thats weird. Hope you are going to inbound chage set and then clicking on 'view source' link beside button name.

Comment: Check to see which pages the buttons are used on. It's possible that if you didn't also import the pages, the buttons are there, but the changes weren't applied because the Visualforce pages weren't also updated. You might find the button code is there as new buttons that you need to apply to your existing pages. Everything is related and it may not have all of the pieces that were needed to fully implement your changes.

Comment: It's not possible, Jestilla.  You're missing something, somehow.  Double check everything.